# Duplicating Excel's representation of Dates in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia I need to convert numbers to `DateTime` in the same manner as Microsoft Excel.

In Excel, today's date of 23-Sep-2019 is represented by 43731 and 6pm this afternoon by 43731.75. I can ignore the fact that [Excel incorrectly assumes that 1900 is a leap year](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year) since all my data is safely beyond that point. Millisecond accuracy is sufficient.

The code below seems to work, but is there a better way?

```
function exceldatetodate(exceldate::Integer)
    Dates.Date(1899, 12, 30) + Dates.Day(exceldate)
end
function exceldatetodate(exceldate::Real)
    t,d = modf(exceldate)
    Dates.Date(1899, 12, 30) + Dates.Day(d) + Dates.Millisecond(floor(t * 86400000))
end

julia> exceldatetodate(43731)
2019-09-23

julia> exceldatetodate(43731.75)
2019-09-23T18:00:00
```

Comment: Have you checked how `XLSX.jl` handles it (https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl)? I don't know if there's a better way. But if there isn't already, this would be a great thing to add to `XLSX.jl`. I'd wait around for a better answer, but if none come up, you should open an issue there.

Answer (score 1):

you can overload the `convert` methods, and create a custom type that holds the value.

```
using Dates

struct ExcelDate{T<:Real}  
   val::T
end

function exceldatetodate(exceldate::Integer)
   Dates.DateTime(1899, 12, 30) + Dates.Day(exceldate)
end
function exceldatetodate(exceldate::Real)
   t,d = modf(exceldate)
   return Dates.DateTime(1899, 12, 30) + Dates.Day(d) + Dates.Millisecond((floor(t * 86400000)))
end

function exceldatetodate(exceldate::ExcelDate)
   exceldatetodate(exceldate.val)
end

function exceldatetodate(exceldate::ExcelDate)
   exceldatetodate(exceldate.val)
end

function toexceldate(date::Date)
   datetime = Dates.value(DateTime(date) - Dates.DateTime(1899, 12, 30))
   datetime = round(datetime/86400000,digits = 3)
   return ExcelDate(datetime)
end

function toexceldate(date::DateTime)
   datetime = Dates.value(date - Dates.DateTime(1899, 12, 30))
   datetime = round(datetime/86400000,digits = 3)
   return ExcelDate(datetime)
end


Base.convert(d::Type{Dates.DateTime},n::ExcelDate) = exceldatetodate(n) 
Base.convert(d::Type{Dates.Date},n::ExcelDate) = convert(Date,exceldatetodate(n))
Base.convert(d::Type{T},n::ExcelDate) where T<: Real = convert(d,n.val)
Base.convert(d::Type{ExcelDate},n::Dates.DateTime) = toexceldate(n) 
Base.convert(d::Type{ExcelDate},n::Dates.Date) = toexceldate(n)
```

then, you can play with the values:

```
original_numbers = 40000.01:41000.01 #test numbers
excel_dates = convert.(ExcelDate,original_numbers)
dates = convert.(Date,excel_dates) #just days
datetimes = convert.(DateTime,excel_dates) #days and miliseconds
orig2 = convert.(ExcelDate,datetimes) #this preserves the original number
orig3 = convert.(ExcelDate,dates) #this does not preserve the original number
```

Is very important to mention that excel treats all numbers as float64, where in Julia, Dates are a completely different type. In my opinion, if you want a certain range of numbers to behave like a Date, it's better to construct a type that reflects that behavior. 
One important characteristic of a excel date is that you can operate over dates like numbers, but the result of that operation isn't formatted as a date. That is a result of Excel's decision of using a Float64 to represent Dates. 
The defined type has more restrictions than a number, and if you want to work with the dates as numbers, you can transform the `ExcelDate`'s as numbers first, but it makes more sense to just use the julia `Date` type, that has better and more methods to to use with dates.
Offtopic, but dates are a not solved problem of programming, with different standards across all programming languages.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion, and overloading `convert` feels very "Julian", which is good. I don't think overloading `+` makes sense though (it's carefully not defined for type `Date`). And overloading `-` should probably not return another `ExcelDate` just as subtracting two `Date`s returns a `Period` rather than a `Date`.

Comment: yeah, you are right, in excel, the "behavior" is to format the operation of two dates as a number. I'm gonna correct that

Comment: @PhilipSwannell Note that `+(::Date, ::Date)` is not defined, but `+(::Date, ::Time)` is. Personally, I don't really like that second method - I think the constructor `DateTime(::Date, ::Time)` (which is also defined) is sufficient and sensical.

Comment: It is probably worth emphasizing that this answer applies to any language that uses `Float64` to represent `DateTime`, as long as you adjust the epoch date appropriately. So for example, while Excel uses 1899-12-31, Matlab uses 0-0-0 (but otherwise everything is identical).